# Event listeners not being added, Typescript, HTML

Tags: html, typescript, events, frontend

I'm having some trouble dynamically creating buttons and adding functionality to them. Full code is quite large, so I'll try to recreate the minimal amount to reproduce the problem here. The code bellow is expected to create buttons in the targeted div with the button content stored as key in ChoiceBox.choices and its function stored as value in ChoiceBox.choices. The buttons are created, however functionality is only added to the last button.

Also made a fiddle if anyone prefers it: https://jsfiddle.net/0z5tr6yq/1/

index.html - just a div with an id

```html
<div id="ChoiceBox" style="position: absolute; right: 40%; top: 30vh; width: 300px; max-height: 450px; min-height: 50px; background-color: rgba(43, 42, 42, 1);">

</div>
```

index.ts

```ts
import {choiceBox} from "choiceBox"

let cb = new ChoiceBox()

let choices:Map<string, ()=>void> = new Map()
choices.set("Option1", ()=>{console.log("Option1")})
choices.set("Option2", ()=>{console.log("Option2")})
choices.set("Option3", ()=>{console.log("Option3")})

cb.setChoices(choices)
cb.open()
```

choiceBox.ts

```ts
export class ChoiceBox{
    choices:Map<string, ()=>void> = new Map()
    div:HTMLElement

    constructor(){
        let d = document.getElementById("ChoiceBox")
        if(!d){
            throw new Error("no element found")
        }
        this.div = d
    }

    setChoices(choices: Map<string, ()=>void>){
        this.clear()
        this.choices = choices
        console.log(choices)
    }
    clear(){
        this.choices = new Map()
        this.div.innerHTML = ``
    }
    open(){
        //...
        this.choices.forEach((v, k)=>{
            this.createButton(k, v)
        })
    }
    private createButton(k:string, f:()=>void){
        let inner = `<a href ="#" id="${k+this.div.id}_test" class="btn devbtn">${k}</a><br>`        
        this.div.innerHTML += `${inner}`
        //bind test to button
        let t = document.getElementById(k+this.div.id+"_test")
            if(!t){
                console.error("No button with id of: "+ k+this.div.id+"_test")
            }else{
                //console log for debugging
                //console.log(t)
                t.addEventListener("click", f)
            }
    }

}
```

Expected to create buttons in the targeted div with the button content stored as key in ChoiceBox.choices and its function stored as value in ChoiceBox.choices. The buttons are created, however functionality is only added to the last button.

Edit: Changing `this.div.innerHTML +=` ${inner}`` to `this.div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",inner)` fixed the problem. Tnx for the help.

Comment: `this.div.innerHTML += \`${inner}`\` innerHTML removes event listeners....

Comment: @ epascarello  Ty. Changing `this.div.innerHTML += `${inner}` to `this.div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",inner)` fixed the problem